# Oracle - Regular expression - Keep reducing a char to match to another column

Tags: regex, oracle

I have 2 columns from 2 different tables - say columnA and columnB, which I am matching with each other. However, if they do not match then I want to remove last one char from columnB and again match with columnA. If it still won't match then reduce one more char at the end from columnB and try to match. Keep reducing chars from columnB till there is match ( and untill columnB turns to 0 length).

Ex - ColumnA has a value "ABC" and columnB has "ABCDEF". 
Then, since "ABC" is not equal to "ABCDEF", try to match "ABCDE" with "ABC". Since it is not matching then try "ABCD" . Since there is still no match then try "ABC" . Now there is match and so stop !!

I am unable to come with a regular expression in Oracle to handle this. I can use substr/length and bunch of "OR" conditions but I will prefer to avoid that if there is regular expression, which can do it nicely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about just `column_b like column_a || '%'`?

Comment: What's wrong with the substring approach? You are looking for columnB that starts with columnA. `columnA = SUBSTR(columnB, 1, LENGTH(columnA))` seems perfect for this. (Mureinik's suggestion is too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( columnb, '^'||columna||'.*$' );
```

(However, this has issues when `columna` contains `^$.*+?|[]{}()\` characters).

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  columnb LIKE columna||'%';
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  INSTR( columnb, columna ) = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR( columnb, 1, LENGTH( columna ) ) = columna;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is may be you want to find the longest prefix of two strings.
In my opinion, it's easier to do in PL/SQL than in SQL:

```
create or replace function longest_prefix(a varchar2, b varchar2) return varchar2 as
    l number :=least(length(a), length(b));
    l_common varchar2(32767) :=substr(a,1,l);
begin
    for i in 1..l loop
        if substr(a,i,1)!=substr(b,i,1) then
            l_common:=substr(a,1,i-1);
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return l_common;
end;
/
```

Test:

```
SQL> select longest_prefix('asdf', 'as23') from dual;

LONGEST_PREFIX('ASDF','AS23')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
as
```